# The simplest form for $x_j$ if $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{x_j}{i+j-1}=1,~ 1\le i \le n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, binomial-coefficients

If $$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{x_j}{i+j-1}=1,~ 1\le i \le n,$$
$x_j$ can be found by considering a system of linear simultaneous equations: $\sum_{j=1}^nH_{ij} ~ x_j=1, 1\le i \le n$, where $H_{ij}$ is the Hilbert matrix.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix
The question here is: How to find the simplest form for $x_j$ by this method or otherwise? To re-emphasize, eventually, $x_j$ would be a function of $j$ and $n$ only.

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A331431](https://oeis.org/A331431) has the answer:  T(n,k) = (-1)^(n+k)*(n+k+1)*binomial(n,k)*binomial(n+k,k) for n >= k >= 0..

Comment: @Somos Very good, so a proof(s) will be welcome now.

Comment: For a proof I suggest using [WIlf-Zeilberger pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair) method.

Comment: Consider $f(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_j}{t+j-1}$.  Then $f(1)=f(2)=\ldots=f(n)=1$.  It is evident that
$$f(t)=1-\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{t-j}{t+j-1}.$$
Therefore
$$x_i=\lim_{t \to -i+1} (t+i-1)f(t)=\frac{(-1)^{n-i}(n+i-1)!}{(i-1)!(i-1)!(n-i)!}.$$

Comment: The last comment should be an answer...

Comment: @metamorphy Yes, I also wonder why it was not posted as an answer, so I have up-voted the comment itself. Also my own answer was little involved. But I will try to post it ip.